# How can I convert this code to work with async?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="users">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**TS FILE**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {};
  users: any;
  ngOnInit() {
   this.subscription = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(users => {
    this.users = users;
   })
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

i want to avoid manually unsubscribing and want to use async. How can i convert this to work with async pipe because when i try

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users | async">{{ user.name }}</li>
```

i get

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular async pipe allows the subscription to observables inside of the angular template syntax. It also takes care of unsubscribing from observables automatically. So you Shouldn't subscribe that.
TS FILE

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.users = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}
```

HTML

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users | async">{{ user.name }}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is users | async enough in ngIf directive ?

Comment: @Michel your welcome , yes it is, *ngIf="observable$ | async"

Comment: Thanks.I accepted your answer.So after in the ngOnInit if i need to access the data in the typescript file then i just use subscribe ?

Comment: @Michel your welcome , you can subscribe or  use pipe(tap( res=>{/* access the data*/}))

Comment: The idea is not to use subscribe at all,how can i get the value now in typescript value

Comment: @Michel if you subscribe the observable you cant subscribe it any more . but if you pipe it i think it is possible

Comment: @Michel please post new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006559/how-can-i-get-values-from-observable-without-using-subscribe

Comment: I posted Arash. Here is the link

Comment: @Michel did you try pipe(tap( res=>{console.log(res)}))

Answer (score 0):

You can use async pipe if you have an observable. Since you subscribed to it, the restul is no longer an observable.

So try something like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {};
    users: any;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.users = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    }
}
```