# How can i get values from observable without using subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

When i started learning angular i readed blogs that using async pipe is better because it makes automatically unsubscribe from the data stream. So i do

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="users | async">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let user of users | async">{{ user.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**TS FILE**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {};
  users: any;
  ngOnInit() {
   this.users = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userss');
   console.log(this.users);
  }
}
```

so in the ngOnInit method the console log

```
console.log(this.users);
```

gives me

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator
```

I got the values in HTML with the async pipe, but what if i will need to do some logic in my componenet - ts file based on the users that i got from backend.

If i want the data inside i could do it with subscribe. But i don't want that because at first place i started with async pipe because  i don't want to manualy unsubscribe from it.

So in this situation how can i get the value from the observable without subscribe so at the end when the
component is detroyed i should not care about unsubscribing.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190375/how-can-i-await-on-an-rx-observable

Comment: I don't want to convert to promise

Comment: If you don't want to transform this.user into Promise, you can create another variable and store in it the user data.

Comment: If converthing to promise if the only what to get this done then okay...

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the `users` in your component? If you call a function in your component from your template you could pass the `users` from your template to that function and have access to the users in a function that way.

Comment: No, calling function in HTML is not good because of change detection...

Comment: @Michael12312 in meant calling a function on an event like `(click)="myfunc(users)"`, which is fine. You should describe what you actually want to do in more detail.

Comment: No need to unsubscribe from Angular HTTP calls, they close automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some transformations inside the Observable simply use `map` pipe-able operator:

```
onlyActiveUsers: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.onlyActiveUsers$ = this.http
     .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userss')
     .pipe(
        map(users => {
           const transformedUsers = users.filter(user => user.isActive);
           return transformedUsers;
        })
     )
  }
```

You can use `| async` pipe for the variable `onlyActiveUsers$` in your template.

If you want to store some values inside your component before or after the transformation, use `tap`:

```
onlyActiveUsers: Observable<any[]>;
allUsers: any[];

ngOnInit() {
   this.onlyActiveUsers$ = this.http
     .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userss')
     .pipe(
        tap(allUsers => this.allUsers = allUsers), // here, or after "map" below
        map(users => {
           const transformedUsers = users.filter(user => user.isActive);
           return transformedUsers;
        })
     )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know this doesn't answer your original question of how to get the
> value without subscribe, but I am posting as you may not be aware of
> this approach which simulates the behavior of async from the subscribe
> pipeline.

---

Per maxime's comment below, you could implement the `takeUntil` operator as a solution as well.

- Reference his explination below regardining the differences.

  ```
  ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userss')
       .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
       .subscribe(val => this.users = val)

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
  }
  ```

---

I use the `take` operator for this.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take

> take returns an Observable that emits only the first count values
> emitted by the source Observable. If the source emits fewer than count
> values then all of its values are emitted. `After that, it completes, regardless if the source completes.`

The bellow will take one value and auto-unsubscribe similar to the async pipe.

```
this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userss')
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(val => this.users = val)
```

Comment: This is in no way the same as the async pipe. The async pipe keeps a stream open until its host is destroyed. Whether because there's an ngIf at this level or the host component is being destroyed (ngIf higher up or new route for example). So if you're making an HTTP call which takes let say 10s to resolve and you move to another component, the option with take(1) would still run in the background even if the component is being destroyed but that wouldn't be the case with the async pipe. If you wanted an equivalent you could hook into the ngOnDestroy, emit void in a subject and do a takeUntil

Comment: @maxime1992 this is true, I have included your approach as a viable implementation and is certainly a point of concern using the `take` approach around `HTTP.get`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with the async pipe is totally fine. But what it will do for you is subscribing to the observable, because of that you get the data. It will also handle to unsubscribe, because of that using the async pipe is very convenient.

And this is the nature of observables: you only get values if you subscribe to it.

If you want to have the values in your component you need to subscribe.